# How to save graphic create by Graphics.DrawLine on PictureBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Its the possibility to save graphic create with Graphics.DrawLine on PictureBox with picture from this Picturebox?

Its  seen like this:

http://pl.tinypic.com/r/140k6xf/8

My drawing function:

```
 Public Sub PictureBox2_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
    If PictureBox1.Image Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Upload Image first", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    Else


        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox1.Image)

        Dim blackpen As New Drawing.Pen(ColorDialog1.Color, 0.5)
        Dim currPoint As Point

        Dim drawFont As New Font("Arial", 8)
        Dim drawBrush As New SolidBrush(ColorDialog1.Color)
        Dim drawFormat As New StringFormat
        drawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center

        g = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics()

        If previousPoint.IsEmpty = True Then
            previousPoint = New Point(e.X - 231, e.Y - 52)
            MPx1 = e.X
            MPy1 = e.Y
        Else
            currPoint = New Point(e.X - 231, e.Y - 52)
            MPx2 = e.X
            MPy2 = e.Y
            g.DrawLine(blackpen, previousPoint, currPoint)


            res = ((((MPx1 - MPx2) ^ 2) + ((MPy1 - MPy2) ^ 2)) ^ 0.5) / Val(Label11.Text)
            g.DrawString(res, drawFont, drawBrush, currPoint, drawFormat)
            previousPoint = New Point(0, 0)

        End If
        blackpen.Dispose()
        drawFont.Dispose()
        drawBrush.Dispose()
        drawFormat.Dispose()
        g.Dispose()
    End If
```

I'm loading picture in another procedure, then add lines by DrawLine and I need to save it. I try using some various examples from internet, but in my case it dosen't work. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Use Graphics.FromImage() instead of PictureBox1.CreateGraphics(). You'll modify image currently displayed in your Picture Box. You started right with that but you're then overwriting g variable. You may also need to force a PictureBox refresh after this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to create a new Bitmap, paint your graphics content on it using [Graphics.DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42807xh1(v=vs.110).aspx), and then save using [Bitmap.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah(v=vs.110).aspx).